# Kubuntu switch two last language layouts like MacOS or Gnome

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, language-support, plasma-5

I use three different keyboard layouts. In Gnome and MacOS, switching between languages is conveniently implemented - when you press once Win+Space it switches between the last two languages, and to select the third one, you need to press Win+Space twice. Is it possible to do this in Kubuntu?

Comment: I wonder if you succeed in configuring?